# How to change style of AppBarLayout in the entire theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-appbarlayout

I want to do something very simple: Change the background for the `AppBarLayout` component for the entire theme.

So here's my theme, where I don't know which attribute to overwrite:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Some color attributes that doesn't actually matter... -->

</style>
```

And here's the new theme for `AppBarLayout` that I want to apply to the above theme:

```
<style name="DefaultAppBarLayout" parent="Widget.Design.AppBarLayout">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Should I be inheriting styles from another parent for the `BaseTheme`? Or which `<item name="attribute_name"></item>`should I apply my new style to?

## EDIT 1

[image: Current behavior]

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/more_actionbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:title="@string/moremenu_fragment_title"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

This is the code that I want to write; without specifying every single time "background color = white"

[image: Desired behavior]

Code that works for it; but I don't want to write `android:background="@color/colorTrueWhite"` for every `AppBarLayout` in my XMLs

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorTrueWhite">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/more_actionbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:title="@string/moremenu_fragment_title"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: change with what?

Comment: Overwrite AppBarLayout style to the specified below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some higher version than `1.0.0` of the google material implementation for android dependecy they added the `appBarLayoutStyle`. I was using that version when I asked this question. I guess now it's kind of pointless but yeah... the solution is to upgrade to a newer version of the material design library and use the customizable attribute in your `<style name="AppTheme">`

Answer (score 0):

in you manifest make sure your add default style **BaseTheme** This will apply to every activity in your application. and if you want some other theme for different activity add specific theme to a activity.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_logo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/BaseTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

make you style something like this.

```
   <style name="BaseTheme" parent="DefaultAppBarLayout">
        <!-- Some color attributes that doesn't actually matter... -->
    </style>

    <style name="DefaultAppBarLayout" parent="Widget.Design.AppBarLayout">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

add this line in your theme

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
```

#FF0000 is red color change it to any color you want.

Comment: The theme is set both in the Application and the activities and I have other custom styling going on that works perfectly. I need to change at theme level the style of `AppBarLayout` component. Which I don't know which attribute of the theme to overwrite

Comment: can you explain with the image and some code what you exactly want.

Comment: if you want to create your custom them don't add parent then. Because parent will bring some pre-define features. Make a style without parent. and then add this style as parent into some other style

Comment: I want all the parent attributes, except for the one that I want to change. Check my edit in the question

Comment: oh in that case just change the primary color in your theme to white or wherever you want

Comment: The problem is that all other components that rely on the `colorPrimary` (and I want them to rely on it) are going to change to white and it's going to be a lot more work than specifying background to the AppBarLayout

Answer (score 0):

You have your `BaseTheme`, so make it parent to `DefaultAppBarLayout`.
So you are applying changes from `DefaultAppBarLayout` to `BaseTheme`.

Code:

`<style name="BaseTheme" parent="DefaultAppBarLayout"> <!-- Some color attributes that doesn't actually matter... --> </style>`

(Haven't tried yet this method, but I hope it's working)

Edit:
Don't forget to set BaseTheme in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the `appBarLayoutStyle` attribute in the `AppBarLayout` class, but I don't know if it's what you are looking for. If this attribute does not work, a solution is to create a style for all your `AppBarLayout`, specifying the `android:background` attribute and apply `style="@style/YourAppBarLayoutStyle"` in each `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Yes. But I just wanted to know if existed a  property that I could set Theme-wise and it applies for the entire app. Just like "buttonStyle" or similar

Comment: @SomerandomITboy boy Have you tried the appBarLayoutStyle attribute?

Comment: It was not available by the time this question was posted. Will try on monday as soon as I get back to work